# How to clone an NFC tag using iPhone?

Tags: security, encoding, nfc, smart-card

My university card is an NFC card, and I would like to create a duplicate of it. I have tried multiple apps through which I have been able to read it and write other stuff. But I don't know how to write the information contained in my card onto a different tag. Are there any apps on iphone you would suggest for that?

Thanks for your time!